# Calling a .exe as Admin from within my code in Program Files folder

Tags: c#

I have a C# application which calls an .exe file. This executable file must be started with administrator rights. But I don't want to run my application with admin rights.
I use the following code for that:

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("foo.exe");
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
procStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

If I put my application in no specific folder, everything works fine, when calling the executable, the user is asked to run it as admin. But when I put my application in the "Program Files" folder and start it, when calling the execution file, there is NO question to run it as admin. And because of that, execution fails.
I'm using Windows 7 and the executable file is not lying in the "Program Files" folder. Is there a way to always run this file as admin but not my application?

Comment: Could you run it in an isolated AppDomain and pass in specific credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a manifest to the target application stating that it should be run as admin. The responsibility for that generally lies with the application being started, not the application which starts it.

An exception would be cases like Notepad being called to open a shared configuration file, but you haven't provided enough details to determine that.

Comment: I'm not sure if that works for non .NET applications as the executable file is. But I found a mistake in my code: I'm doing a copy operation before the execution call and this function rised the problem. Avoiding that, I can call the executable even with the "runas" parameter and everything works fine :) Nevertheless thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just Add a new **`Application manifest file`** in your project and

change this `<requestedExecutionLevel>` as

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```